Understanding this ratio trick

Two numbers are in the ratio $3:5.$ If $9$ is subtracted from each, they become in the ratio $12:23.$ Find the smaller number.
Solution
Let's denote the two numbers as $3x$ and $5x$.
According to the problem: $ \dfrac{3x - 9}{5x - 9} = \dfrac{12}{23}$
Cross-multiplying: $$23(3x - 9) = 12(5x - 9)\\69x
- 207 = 60x - 108\\x = 11$$
Therefore, the smaller number $3x$ is $33$.


There is a trick to solving this problem. The difference between $12$ and $23$ is $11.$ If you multiply $11$ to $3$ and $5$ you get $33$ and $55.$ So, the smaller number is $33.$

I understand the above solution. How does the trick work, though?

Think about it for a moment. How can this "trick" be correct advice when it does not consider the fact that the number we subtracted was $9$ and not some completely different number?

The trick is fake: it claims that $ \dfrac{3x - 18}{5x - 18} = \dfrac{12}{23}$ has solution $23-12=11$ while its actual solution is $22.$

hint: try solving for $\frac{ax-c}{bx-c}$=$\frac{d}{e}$
when you will try to solve it you'll get $x=\frac{c(e-d)}{ae-bd}$
and when you'll do that  you'll find that the trick is just a coincidence because the numbers in the original ratio will be $ax:bx$ and in your case $x=|d-e|$ which is not true for all cases

as a final nod try  this  trick for other numbers,this trick will be false where $\frac{c}{ae-bd}$ =1

Do you mean the trick will be false unless $\frac{c}{ae-bd}=1$? That equation happens to be true in the original question.

Oh yeah thanks for telling me
